# Expected value of the push-forward of a random measure and its expected value

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $M\subset\mathbb{R}^d$. Consider a mapping $X:\Omega\times M \to M$ and a function $f:\Omega\times M\to\mathbb{R}$. I am concerned with the expected value of the push forward of $f$ with the mapping $X$ in the following form:

Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[X_\#f] = \mathbb{E}[X_\#\mathbb{E}[f]]$? Notice that the push forward is in $M$ but the expectation in $\Omega$, namely

$$ \int_M \phi(x)\mathbb{E}[X_\#f](x)dx = \iint_{M\times\Omega} \phi(x) X(\omega,\cdot)_\#f(\omega,x) dx d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \iint_{M\times\Omega} \phi(X(\omega,x)) f(\omega,x) dx d\mathbb{P}(\omega)  $$
and
$$ \int_M \phi(x)\mathbb{E}[X_\#\mathbb{E}[f]](x)dx = \iint_{M\times\Omega} \phi(X(\omega,x)) \int_\Omega f(\omega',x) d\mathbb{P}(\omega') dx d\mathbb{P}(\omega)  $$
for all $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ regular enough.

I would be happy with both affirmative or negative answers. I am especially concerned with random functions $f$ of the form $f=Y_\# f_0$ where $Y$ is a mapping like $X$ and $f_0:M\to M$ is not random (not defined in $\Omega$).

**Edit**: It might be clarifying to state what I mean with push-foward of a density without messing with other variables. Given a map $X:M\to M$ and a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^d$, I define $X_\#f$ to be

$$ \int_M \phi(x)X_\#f(x)dx = \int_M \phi(X(x))f(x)dx $$

for any $\phi$ sufficiently regular. Notice that this is nothing but the push-forward of the measure $d\mu(x) = f(x)dx$, and can be stated as well via $ X_\#\mu(A) = \mu(X^{-1}A) $ for any Borel $A\subset M$.

Comment: I am familiar with push forwards of measures along maps, but what is a pushforward of a random variable long the map, with which it share the domain, but co-domain of one is different from the domain of another?

Comment: @SBF I wrote what I mean by this push forward in the question. In this context it can be understood as (for fixed omega) the push forward of a density in x, namely some measure f(.,x)dx that is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue.

Comment: You have a Lebesgue measure on a metric space? I also see no definition of push forward given. What is $X_* f$ and $X_*\Bbb Ef$?

Comment: @SBF I changed the definition of M in the question to avoid confusion. I want to think of M as a subset of Rd, I could counsider some measurable metric space but this is enough. In the mathematical formulas I give the definition of the push-forward $X(\omega,⋅)_\#f(\omega,x)$ for fixed $\omega$ in the question, it's the only formula I wrote. This is a push-forward in the x variable.

Comment: Ok, so this is not a push forward of a measure. I’m confused, and won’t be able help. Perhaps having a precise definition of what a push forward in $x$ is, better not involving any extra data such as $\omega$ would be helpful to others

Comment: @SBF Okay, I will do that, thank you for your feedback

Comment: Ok, so for each $\omega$ you get that $f(\omega, x)\mathrm dx$ is some measure on $M$? Let's denote it by $\kappa(\mathrm dx|\omega)$. Then you're talking about $\mu(\mathrm dx|\omega) := (X(\omega)_\#\kappa(\cdot|\omega))(\mathrm dx)$. Correct?

Comment: @SBF Exactly! That's what I mean.